# How to reference FARPROC in c

Tags: c, windows

I need to read the first 4 bytes in a given win32 API function .
how to reference FARPROC type and use it as normal pointer in c code ?

```
HMODULE h = GetModuleHandle(L"user32.dll");
FARPROC msgBox = GetProcAddress(h, "MessageBoxA");
```

Comment: What do you mean that you "need to read the first 4 bytes in a given win32 API function"? Why do you need to read those four bytes? What is the *actual* problem you have? What is the reason behind your proposed solution?

Comment: i'm trying to read the first assembly instructions in the function to replace with a hook jump .

Comment: Then perhaps you should ask about that instead? And when doing that, please show us what you have tried, and tell us how that worked or didn't work. And please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This is a typical [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @SherifMagdy, I don't think the OS will let you write to a shared library.

Comment: What do you mean by "normal" pointer, or even an "abnormal" one?  A `FARPROC` type is a function pointer.   A function pointer is typed, just like any other except a `void *`.

Comment: I think the question should be titled "How to dereference a FARPROC?"

Comment: Are you familiar with [Microsoft Detours](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52586)?

Comment: @Ajay-brahmakshatriya 1. You can write to anything loaded in your processes address space. 2. You can't deref code, it doesn't have a fixed size

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to cast the pointer directly to a char pointer

```
 unsigned char *code = (unsigned char*)msgBox;
```

You may have to change the page protection before writing using [VirtualProtect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366898(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: When I said you cannot write to the shared libraries I meant that the call to `VirtualProtect` on the virtual address mapped to a shared library would fail.

Comment: @ajay-brahakshatriya You can write to shared libraries, Every process has it's own copy in it's address space...